# Tetris AI - Issues understanding Breadth First Search

Tags: java, algorithm, breadth-first-search

I'm making Tetris as a fun side project (not homework) and would like to implement AI so the computer can play itself. The way I've heard to do it is use BFS to search through for available places, then create an aggregate score of the most sensible drop location...

But I'm having trouble understanding the algorithm. So far, the way I understand it is:

1) Add nodes to ArrayList

- `nodeList.add(n nodes)`

2) Connect nodes

- use adjacency matrix: `adjMatrix[sizeOfNodeList][sizeOfNodeList]`
- pass in nodes to connect: ex: `connectNode(nodeA, nodeB);`, which calls: `connectNode(Node from, Node to)`:

  ```
  int fromNode=nodesList.indexOf(from);
  int toNode=nodesList.indexOf(to);

  //connect node A to B and B to A, set that i,j position = 1
  adjMatrix[fromNode][toNode]=1;
  adjMatrix[toNode][fromNode]=1;
  ```

[image]

After nodes have been connected in the adjacency matrix...

3) Loop through Queue of nodes, and add visited to queue

- Create a new Queue: `Queue q = new LinkedList();`
- Add `rootNode` to Queue: `q.add(rootNode)`
- Set visited flag to true: `rootNode.visited(true)`

**This is the part I don't understand...**

- while Queue is not empty... you're supposed to create a new Node and set it equal to the Queue's removed node: `Node n = (Node)q.remove()`

But if you're adding nodes to it `q.add(rootNode)` and `q.add(child)`, when would it ever be empty?

- Next, check while child node = an unvisited child node and is not null, `while((child=getUnvisitedChildNode(n))!=null)`, you're supposed to change child's visited status = `true` then add it to the Queue, `q.add(child)`... but aren't you doing all this `while(!q.isEmpty())`? So when would the `q` be empty if you're adding to it?

What is the purpose of my Queue `q`? Is it the resulting queue?

Thanks

Comment: The purpose of the queue employed in almost all implementations of BFS is to keep the nodes that still need to be processed. You start out with one node, put all its neighbors into the queue, and mark the node as processed/give it a time stamp. Then you proceed to the next node at the front of the queue, doing the same; you keep going until there are no more nodes to be taken out of the queue, because then you will have processed all nodes reachable from the source node you started out with.

Comment: The exact same code, exchanging the queue for a stack, will give you a DFS. The difference is only the order the data structures queue and stack maintain on the objects you process: queue is FIFO, stack is LIFO.

Comment: I suggest you try and run a BFS on paper on a very small, arbitrary graph, say 10 nodes or so, to get a feeling for the algorithm. You could keep track of the queue by writing down its content and crossing out the nodes that were already taken out of the queue. Once you did that, everything should be a lot clearer.

Comment: What's important is NOT to put nodes in the queue again that were already processed, because then you'd get infinite loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your queue `q` holds the nodes you haven't yet visited. You should only add to your queue `q` nodes that haven't already been visited. That way it will become empty, nodes that you have already explored will not reenter the list.

Using your image as an example, you will start `q` only with the node `A`. You'll mark `A` as visited. This is how you start.

Your loop will consist of removing the first node on the queue `q`, in this case `A`, and add all of the nodes that are connected to `A` and haven't been visited yet. In other words, you'll traverse the line of the matrix for `A` and find that `B`, `C` and `D` are connected to `A`. For each of them, if `visited()` returns false, you'll add them to `q` and mark as visited. In this pass, `q` will have `B`, `C` and `D`, and all of `A-D` will have visited() as true.

In the next iteration, the first node on `q` will be `B`. You'll dequeue it and see that it is connected to `A`, `E` and `F`. Since `A` returns `true` when you call `visited()`, you will not add it to `q`. `E` and `F` will be added and marked as visited.

If you continue, you will dequeue `C`, `D`, `E` and `F`, without adding anything to `q`, since all the nodes have already been visited. After that, `q.isEmpty()` will return `true` and your loop is over.

Comment: @Growler I expanded my answer to try to give you an example of the algorithm's execution. See if this makes it clear now.

Comment: Thank you for your in-depth analysis! It really helped me! Can you explain why Queue is used for BFS and Stack is used for DFS? Thanks! I will accept your answer now though

Comment: The Stack alters the order in which the elements are visited. In the example, when put B, C and D in the stack, in the next iteration, the first node you'll visit will be D, because it will be on top of the others in the stack. It has no new nodes to visit, so we move on to C. C is popped and F goes into the stack. F is now on top of B, so we pop F first, no new nodes are added, then we pop B, adding E, which is the last node. In each iteration, you will always start by the last node you visited, going deeper and deeper into the tree instead of exploring a whole level.

Comment: In a nutshell, the algorithms are essentialy the same. The choice of data structure, either a queue or a stack, will determine the order in which the nodes are visited, breadth-first or depth-first.

Answer (score 1):

The queue is your to-do list.  It is the list of nodes to be processed next.

The queue will become empty when you run out of children to process, at the leaves of the tree/graph.

Comment: Does your To Do list start off with every node, or just the next node to be processed?

Comment: @Growler you should start only with the root node. From it the others will be added.

Comment: Just the next node or nodes (plural) go into the queue.  This is how the "breadth-first" bit of the algorithm is achieved.  All level one nodes are processed (the root node), then all level twos (the root's children), then all level threes (their children), and so on.  As you noted, it is also important to have some kind of mechanism like a `visited` flag to make sure that you don't revisit old nodes and thus create infinite cycles.